# Amplify custom email on change password

Tags: amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

Where are located the email message on AWS, it is in Cognito?

When a user ask to change his email, it calls this function:

Auth.forgotPassword()

But I can't find where to change the email message (the body, the content).

Currently is a custom message that the previous developer did but I can't find where is it

Comment: Found the answer here in case you're still looking:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67288498/amplify-custom-email-on-change-password

Comment: Found the answer here in case you're still looking:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50591999/different-email-verification-messages-for-sign-up-and-forgot-password

Answer (score 1):

You can customise email verification messages under the Message Templates heading in the Messaging tab of your user pool.(For small changes)

Need fully customise use the following link
https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/aws-cognito-customize-emails

NB: Now the above Link Is not active

Answer (score -1):

You cant change your email address if the email address is your credential. if you use a username as a credential then you can update the email.

Comment: I asked how to change the email message (body) not the address. Currently I have a custom message, but I don't know where should I chage it, that's my question. Is the message were goes the 6 numer code for password recovery validation